# Power BI Slicer affecting some visuals but not others

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Why does my Slicer in Power BI only affect some visuals but not others? How do I make it affect all visuals on the same page in Power BI Desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I did not set up the relationships correctly.

In order to set up relationships, go to `Home > Manage Relationships`.

Once I set them up correctly, this solved my problem

Comment: Nice job sharing your solution with the community! That’s helpful. You might also click the checkbox to mark your question as answered.

Comment: For other people’s reference the other thing to check is Edit Interactions as it is possible you changed a slicer not to filter some visuals:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-reports-visual-interactions

Comment: I can't accept my answer for another 15 hours, but feel free to give me an upvote ;)